# What is impact of using jul-to-slf4j several times in Java EE / Spring container?

Tags: tomcat, jaxb, slf4j, logback, java.util.logging

Usual instruction to bridge JUL to SLF4J is adding to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

adding to `logback.xml`:

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"/>
```

adding to Spring beans:

```
<bean class="org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler" init-method="install"/>
```

Note that I am don't include:

```
<bean class="org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler"
      init-method="removeHandlersForRootLogger"/>
```

because that [remove Tomcat's/JBoss's etc logging registrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867514/jul-to-slf4j-for-specific-classes-only). One reason for containers to register to JUL - to redirect console output to file, but I am not sure if that true.

[Ceki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100970/ceki) (author of Log4j, SLF4J and Logback) [doesn't recommend installing](http://blog.cn-consult.dk/2009/03/bridging-javautillogging-to-slf4j.html) `SLF4JBridgeHandler` multiply times. But he didn't explain why...

What does happen if two webapp register `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()` simultaneously in single Tomcat? Do they conflict? Do one steal all log messages from other?

JAXB-RS implementation from `com.sun.jersey.*` uses JUL logging and I want redirect log statements per application instead of system `catalina.log`

Another strange recommendation is to put `jul-to-slf4j.jar` into `lib/` dir of container and do not include with application. Why?

**REFERENCE ON THE TOPIC**:

- [how do I setup slf4j to handle JUL logging in a HttpServlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364904/how-do-i-setup-slf4j-to-handle-jul-logging-in-a-httpservlet)
- [jul-to-slf4j for specific classes only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867514/jul-to-slf4j-for-specific-classes-only)
- [How to use log4j to see into Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437043/how-to-use-log4j-to-see-into-jersey)
- [JUL to SLF4J Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117030/jul-to-slf4j-bridge)
- http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2012/11/logging-with-slf4j-and-logback-in.html
- [Handler error in SLF4JBridgeHandler in tomcat logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472801/handler-error-in-slf4jbridgehandler-in-tomcat-logs)
- http://blog.cn-consult.dk/2009/03/bridging-javautillogging-to-slf4j.html
- http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html
- http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html
- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#LevelChangePropagator
- http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2012-August/003385.html
- http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/07/30/enterprise-spring-framework-best-practices-part-3-xml-config/
- https://github.com/gordonad/enterprise-spring-best-practices/blob/master/02-application-architecture/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-bootstrap.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open request to improve documentation: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-351

Response is:

```
There is one j.u.l.LogManager instance per JVM.
Thus, any manipulation of it impacts the whole JVM.
```

So in multi-application container environment jul-to-slf4j should be a single instance per JVM and loaded from system classes or you get hard to explain problems.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your answer is not correct (at least the last part of it).

*(My answer is actually not about the impact of calling `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()` multiple times, but covers the scenario you probably want to achieve - usage of `jul-to-slf4j` within the multiple applications in Tomcat.)*

First of all you have to get familiar yourself with [Tomcat's classloaders](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) and how they are used. The main idea is that each application has its own classloader therefore could contain it's own `jul-to-slf4j.jar`.

Next in the line is [JULI](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html), Tomcat's logging implementation. Take a closer look at the section which talks about custom `LogManager`:

> The key component there is a custom LogManager implementation, that is
>   aware of different web applications running on Tomcat (and their
>   different class loaders). It supports private per-application logging
>   configurations.

Now let's take a look at the source code of [jul-to-slf4j](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/jul-to-slf4j/src/main/java/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.java). This simple, yet very powerful class, does **nothing** out of the box. To enable the bridge you have to attach `SLF4JBridgeHandler` to the root logger. Ceki gave us two options how to do that:

1. By calling static method `org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()`.
2. By specifying the bridge handle within `logging.properties` file.

**ad 1)** The method process following code:

```
java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("").addHandler(new SLF4JBridgeHandler());
```

But hey, we are inside Tomcat's universe, we do not want to use that ugly `java.util.logging.LogManager` manager! We want that enhanced one comming with Tomcat. So forget this method and do not call it from within the Tomcat.

**ad 2)** You remember that enahnced Tomcat's LogManager allows all applications to have **per-application logging configurations** right? And remember that `jul-to-slf4j` could be enabled within `logging.properties` file right?

---

To enable/disable `jul-to-slf4j` bridge within the scope of single application running on Tomcat you have to:

1. Put `jul-to-slf4j.jar` into `/app/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. Create `logging.properties` file within `/app/WEB-INF/classes` with following content: `handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler`.

---

I was strugling with similar issue for a few days and this answer covers one part of my research. Hope it could help you and the others to set up the correct environment with SLF4J in charge.